# ObjectMapper default value of if some fields cannot be cast to object

Tags: java, mongodb, document, objectmapper

I'm new to Java, so apologies if this question is not to the desired standard: I'm loading data from a flat mongodb table and would like to write all the documents into a Pojo, I'm calling it DataClass. My issue is that in some cases the type of the field is not correct. In the below code I'm using `mapper.readValue` to read the Json and cast it to the object. If one of the fields is wrong, the whole loop fails. Is there a way to do it element-wise and just ignore cases where there is a failure or set a default value?

```
List<DataClass> result = new ArrayList<>();
FindIterable<Document> documents = getCollection().find();
for (Document doc : documents) {
    result.add(mapper.readValue(doc.toJson(), DataClass.class));
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for,

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

This will not fail the serialization if the passed json has unknown properties.

Moreover, as per the docs,

> JsonMappingException if the input JSON structure does not match structure
>        expected for result type (or has other mismatch issues)

You can catch `JsonMappingException` if you are looking in that direction.